# drf-spectacular issue with filterset_fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-filter, drf-yasg

I am trying to implement `drf-spectacular` to an existing Django REST API.

However I am getting the following error, when attempting to run

```
./manage.py spectacular --file schema.yml
```

Error:

```
python3.7/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 352, in get_filters
    "%s" % ', '.join(undefined)
TypeError: 'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: client, tenant_id, subtenant_id, data_stream_id
```

The filters do work, but don't seem to play nicely with the drf-spectacular lib. Can anyone please advise on how this might be solved?

Specs as follows:

```
Python                3.7.2
Django                3.0.2    
django-filter         2.2.0    
django-rest-framework 0.1.0    
djangorestframework   3.12.1   
drf-spectacular       0.12.0
```

Viewset example:

```
class subModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Standard ViewSet for the DataStream Model."""
    queryset = DataStream.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataStreamSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ('client', 'tenant_id', 'subtenant_id', 'data_stream_id',)
```

Serializer example:

```
class DataStreamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Class to validate an uploaded DataStream."""

    class Meta:
        """Nested Meta Class."""

        model = DataStream
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Interesting question.  I have hundreds of views and none of them had this particular issue.  The error looks like it is coming from the generated FilterSet (when you define filterset_fields), not spectacular in particular.  Can you run the project normally, and if so can you see the /docs/ page?

Comment: Hi @AndrewBacker, indeed it turns out the problem is with the declared filter_set fields. The specific field names are not one of the models directly, and rather referenced from a Parent model using ForeignKey. 

Once I removed the filter_set from that viewset, it works perfectly. Will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Cool.  I have lots of *other* issues with spectacular but no crashes.  Have you tried to create a custom FilterSet for this view?  It should give you more flexibility while also allowing you to filter on those foreign key linked fields

Comment: there have been massive improvements to `drf-spectacular` (including with `django-filter`) since `0.12.0`. @Rogan88 please check out a newer version. if there are issues remaining, feel free to open a github issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a Viewset that was trying to apply filterset_fields on a `subModel` that did not directly contain those fields, but rather referenced by ForeignKey on another Parent Model. While I thought these filters were working as expected, I think the actual filtering on those fields was being performed by middleware in this case.

Removing the fields from the Viewset allows the schema to be generated with no issue. I am able to access the /docs page fully rendered and /schema endpoint working. Very impressed with `drf-spectacular` thus far.

example model:

```
class DataSteam(models.Model):
    """Class for DataSteam Model."""
    client = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tenant_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subtenant_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data_stream_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class subModel(models.Parent):
    """Class for storing linked datastream records."""
    ds = models.ForeignKey(DataStream, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```